# c++ unorderd_map got me seg fault

Tags: c++

```
#include <unordered_map>
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <utility>
#include <algorithm>
using namespace std;


unordered_map <string, int> setupDictionary(vector<string> book)
{
    unordered_map<string, int> table;
    for (int i =0;i< book.size(); i++)
    {
        string word = book[i];
        if(word != "")
        {
            if (table.find(word)==table.end())
            {
                std::pair<std::string,int> myshopping (word,0);
                table.insert(myshopping);
            }else
            {
                int num = table[word];
                 std::pair<std::string,int> myshopping (word,num+1);
                table.insert(myshopping );
            }

        }
    }
    return table;
}

int main()
{
    vector<string> book;
    book[1] = "hello";
    book[2] = "world";
    book[3] = "hello";
    book[4] = "world2";
    unordered_map < string, int> dict= setupDictionary(book);
   // printf("%s,%d",dict["hello"]);
}
```

Compile and build is good.
But after I run it, I got segmentation fault.
Need help
Dont really know whats wrong in my code.
Thank you indeed!

Answer (score 3):

You never allocated your book vector to have any elements. When you try this line:

```
book[1] = "hello";
```

You are trying to store something when you have not allocated the memory to do so.

Try:

```
book.push_back("hello");
```

instead.

You could also do this:

```
vector<string> book(4);
book[1] = "hello";
...
```

Answer (score 1):

You did not allocate space for the words in your `book` vector. Try like this:

```
vector<string> book(4);
book[0] = "hello";
book[1] = "world";
book[2] = "hello";
book[3] = "world2";
```

Or you could use `push_back()` to insert them at the back one by one.

Plus, indices start from 0, so if you use 1..4 you need a 5 elements vector instead of 4, and you are using more memory than needed.